# Android Studio - Unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: android

I'm currently having problems with the Android Studio. I've seen many questions regarding this issue on the forum. Each has their respective solutions which have appeared to help everyone apart from myself.

The screen shot below shows which dependencies my application is failing on:

[image: Screenshot of the process]

Also to below is my Gradle build class:

[image: Screenshot of Gradle build class]

These are default values, I've tried multiple strategies in order to resolve this situation. Such as:

-Deleting the .Gradle folder within the file system and restarting the studio
-Restart of my system
-Changing the build to offline which throws errors
-Complete install of Android Studio

If anyone can help I'd be very grateful

Comment: Could you please paste the error message when the build process fails?

Comment: Yes I can once it fails again, currently Its resolving the dependencies very very slowly. Fingers crossed it works this time